# JSF 2 + Spring 3: Cannot get it work

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc

I really cannot fix that.
First, I created a Spring Template Project (Spring MVC) from STS.

Then I copied exactly the code reported at http://blog.terrencemiao.com/archives/spring-3-shacks-up-jsf-2-the-maverick-way and it does not work for me.

I think there is at least one error in that code, that is "applicationConfigure.xml should be applicationContext.xml". I corrected it, but it doesn't work yet.

Other than the files reported in that website (same structure), I have:

(1) root-context (WEB-INF/spring)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
 xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                ">  
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
```

(2) servlet-context (WEB-INF/spring/appServlet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.paradise.sandbox" />
```

==============================

The rest is exactly the same. Unfortunately, when I start the server and open localhost:8080/HelloSpring/helloSpring, I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/HelloSpring] threw exception [Circular view path [helloSpring]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/HelloSpring/helloSpring] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [helloSpring]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/HelloSpring/helloSpring] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.traceNextValve(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:116)
>       at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because your InternalViewResolver is looking for helloSpring.jsp file under "/WEB-INF/views/" while the file you have is helloSpring.xhtml.

You can either change the suffix to value ".xhtml" or use an .jsp view file.